Serilog Dynamically Add New Override LogLevel for a namespace
what is the best way to add new Overrides into a configured Serilog Log>
If I set the Override("MyNamespace1") initially, then I can modify the LogLevel for that MyNamespace.
var overrideLevelSwitch = new Serilog.Core.LoggingLevelSwitch();
var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration);
Log.Logger = loggerConfig
    .MinimumLevel.Override("MyNamespace1", overrideLevelSwitch)
    .CreateLogger();

Is there a way to ADD a new namespace dynamically into the Override, say from Controller endpoint,  eg Override("MyNamespace2")? (without pre-defining it when .CreateLogger())
